# how do I solve this equation for t ? (why can't online solvers get it?)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

At first I thought it was straightforward but both my own mathing skills and the free online solvers are failing me. Do I need a better solver? ...is it just unsolvable? How do I know which it is?

Here is the equation:

$$0 = s - 1 + \frac{(2(d-st)(-s) + 2(t+z))\left(1 + \dfrac 1s\right)} {\sqrt{(d-st)^2 + (t+z)^2}}$$

which I want to solve for t. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  This is very hard to read.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site.

Comment: Looks like it can be rearranged into a quadratic in $t$.

Comment: Move the $s-1$ over. Square both sides, multiply everything out. Multiply both sides by the denominator of the RHS. You will have both sides as a quadratic in $t$. Move everything over to one side and use the quadratic formula.

Comment: Free online solvers do not like handing out computing power. If it takes more than a set amount of time (usually a second or two) to compute, they just don't return a result. It's your best bet to use a downloaded program. Most of the online solvers you use also offer paid downloadable versions, but there are very good free, open-source programs available as well.

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5B0%3D%3Ds-1%2B%282%28d-st%29%28-s%29%2B2%28t%2Bz%29%29%281%2B1%2Fs%29%2FSqrt%5B%28d-st%29%5E2%2B%28t%2Bz%29%5E2%5D%2Ct%5D) will do it.

Answer (score 2):

Considering the equation$$0 = s - 1 + \frac{(2(d-st)(-s) + 2(t+z))\left(1 + \dfrac 1s\right)} {\sqrt{(d-st)^2 + (t+z)^2}}$$ start putting things in the lhs and expand the numerator and what is in the square root to get
$$\frac{(1-s) s}{2 (1+s)}=\frac {-(d s+z)+\left(s^2+1\right) t }{\sqrt{\left(d^2+z^2\right)+ 2( z- d s)t+\left(s^2+1\right) t^2} }$$ Square all of it
$$\Big[\frac{(1-s) s}{2 (1+s)}\Big]^2=\frac{(d s+z)^2-2  \left(s^2+1\right) (d s+z)t+\left(s^2+1\right)^2
   t^2 } {\left(d^2+z^2\right)+ 2( z- d s)t+\left(s^2+1\right) t^2  }$$ Now, to make life easier, define a few intermediate constants and write the aquation as
$$c=\frac{a_0+a_1t+a_2t^2}{b_0+b_1t+b_2t^2}$$
Expand again to get
$$(b_0 c-a_0)+ (b_1 c-a_1)t+ (b_2 c-a_2)t^2=0$$
Redefine constants to face
$$A+B t+C t^2=0$$ I strongly suggest to not go back to the original constants if you want to avoid nightmareq;

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a solvable quadratic equation when the terms having $t$ are separated and the equation is squared to reveal the quadratic. After that, all that's left to do is use the quadratic formula to reach the desired result.

This is the result produced by Wolfram Alpha.
[image]

Here is the [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0%3Ds%E2%88%921%2B%28%282%28d%E2%88%92st%29%28%E2%88%92s%29%2B2%28t%2Bz%29%29%281%2B1%2Fs%29%29%2Fsqrt%28%28d%E2%88%92st%29%5E2%2B%28t%2Bz%29%5E2%29+solve+for+t) to the same.